# Android browser - remove outline border when anchor is focused

Tags: css, webkit, android-browser

I am using on my Android app a webview which loades an external page.
It has a few anchors (`<a>` tags). When I press on it, yellow border appears.

How can I prevent it and remove this border ?

I've tried following tricks:

```
// jQuery
$("a").focus(function(){
    $(this).attr("hideFocus", "hideFocus");
});

// CSS
a, :focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

but with no success.

Thanks !

Comment: Shouldn't `a, :focus` be `a:focus`?

Comment: Doesn't `:focus` match all elements that can be focused, even button etc ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Set the CSS property [-webkit-tap-highlight-color](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html) as follows:

```
* { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }
```

Note: setting the color in other ways usually fails because of the way webkit renders the highlight. Depends on version/variant according to my experience.

Comment: -webkit-focus-ring-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);  ?

Answer (score 1):

according to [this](https://medium.com/@hassadee/remove-blue-border-outline-in-chrome-and-dash-border-in-firefox-b857d452d136) post it's better to use

```
a:focus,
button:focus,
input:focus,
textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```