# How to remove visual feedback frame on Samsung Galaxy browser

Tags: android, html, css, browser, samsung-mobile

When a link is clicked a dark orange frame is drawn around it. Sometimes it stays till the next scroll or screen touch.

When some other elements are clicked - the orange frame appears as well sometimes by the size of the clicked element (div, canvas), sometimes bigger.

How this (platform-dependent?) visual feedback tweak is called and (main question) is there a progammatic (javascript?) way to turn it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a (clickable) `canvas` element, surrounded by a fully transparent `div`. The dark orange outline was (surprisingly) generated by a `div` (not `canvas`). Even more surprising - the size of the outline was much bigger than the size of `div` (no other elements - checked). So, I've decided to switch the outline off and this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398763/android-browser-remove-outline-border-when-anchor-is-focused) answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like that's an active style applied by the browser. Try adding this to your css:

```
a:active
{
    border: none;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Update: If that doesn't work you may want to try

```
outline: none;
```

Comment: Hello there. Just tried on both canvas and div (which embraces the canvas). No luck so far.

Comment: Interesting, glad you were able to find a solution.