# Blue overlay of OnClick

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

When I display a html page in Android WebView, there is always a blue overlay on the clicked element which has a href or a javascript function hooked. How do I get rid of this blue overlay?

[image]

Source Code

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Blue Overlay</title>
    <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0;/* get rid of the default 2 pixels margin */
    } 
    body{background-color: #000000;}

    /* button-related CSS */
    a.button{
        background: url("img/icon_bt.png") no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;/*remove the blue underline*/
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
        margin: 50px;
    }
    a.button:active{
        background-image: url("img/icon_bt_pressed.png");
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="button" href="#"></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe this is related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398763/android-browser-remove-outline-border-when-anchor-is-focused

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've [tried it](http://jsfiddle.net/RM96v/3/) with a different image, and it seems to work. Basically, I just added what was suggested in a [different topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398763/android-browser-remove-outline-border-when-anchor-is-focused):

```
a:button {
    ...
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but maybe the image has the blue overlay (and not only the link resp. a-tag). So get rid of it by i.e. `border: 0;` ...